# SQL Create Consecutive Dates Even Count is 0

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join, group-by

i have `log` table that looks like below, i want to collect `log` table for my chart, i want to collect data based on `category` and `date`, scrool down for my sql code

| id | category | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | penghapusan | 2021-08-24 08:23:24 |
| 3 | penghapusan | 2021-08-24 08:24:53 |
| 4 | penerimaan | 2021-08-24 08:27:57 |
| 5 | penerimaan | 2021-08-24 08:28:07 |
| 6 | penerimaan | 2021-08-26 08:31:54 |
| 7 | penolakan | 2021-08-24 08:34:27 |
| 8 | penolakan | 2021-08-24 08:36:16 |
| 9 | penolakan | 2021-08-25 08:38:13 |
| 10 | penolakan | 2021-08-25 08:40:00 |
| 11 | penolakan | 2021-08-25 08:40:13 |
| 12 | penolakan | 2021-08-25 08:41:20 |
| 13 | pengiriman | 2021-08-24 08:41:53 |
| 14 | penolakan | 2021-08-24 08:42:13 |
| 15 | pengiriman | 2021-08-24 08:42:28 |
| 16 | penerimaan | 2021-08-26 08:42:35 |
| 17 | pengiriman | 2021-08-25 08:43:00 |
| 18 | penerimaan | 2021-08-26 08:43:06 |
| 19 | penerimaan | 2021-08-27 08:43:06 |
| 20 | pengiriman | 2021-08-25 08:43:31 |
| 21 | penolakan | 2021-08-24 08:43:37 |
| 22 | penolakan | 2021-08-24 08:43:37 |
| 23 | pengiriman | 2021-08-26 08:44:06 |
| 24 | penolakan | 2021-08-24 08:44:15 |
| 25 | penolakan | 2021-08-24 08:44:15 |
| 26 | pengiriman | 2021-08-26 08:47:36 |
| 27 | penolakan | 2021-08-24 08:47:41 |
| 28 | pengiriman | 2021-08-28 08:48:07 |
| 29 | penerimaan | 2021-08-27 08:48:11 |
| 30 | pengiriman | 2021-08-28 08:48:16 |
| 31 | penerimaan | 2021-08-27 08:48:20 |
| 32 | penghapusan | 2021-08-24 08:48:44 |
| 33 | pengubahan | 2021-08-24 08:48:51 |
| 34 | pengubahan | 2021-08-24 08:49:01 |
| 35 | penghapusan | 2021-08-24 08:49:13 |
| 36 | penghapusan | 2021-08-24 08:52:32 |
| 37 | pembuatan | 2021-08-24 08:52:50 |
| 38 | pembuatan | 2021-08-24 08:53:39 |

here's my code, i'm using count to collect all category data and grouped by category and date (without time)

```
SELECT category, COUNT(category) as total, CAST(date AS DATE) as date
FROM log
GROUP BY category, CAST(date AS DATE)
ORDER BY category ASC
LIMIT 100
```

result from this code down below

| category | total | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pembuatan | 2 | 8/24/2021 |
| pengiriman | 2 | 8/24/2021 |
| pengiriman | 2 | 8/25/2021 |
| pengiriman | 2 | 8/26/2021 |
| pengiriman | 2 | 8/28/2021 |
| penerimaan | 2 | 8/24/2021 |
| penerimaan | 3 | 8/26/2021 |
| penerimaan | 3 | 8/27/2021 |
| penolakan | 8 | 8/24/2021 |
| penolakan | 4 | 8/25/2021 |
| penghapusan | 5 | 8/24/2021 |
| pengubahan | 2 | 8/24/2021 |

well, actually my code it's work, very well. But, if you check the date order for each category, there is a missed date (check for `penerimaan`, no 8/25/2021), my question is, is there a way to overcome the missed date? so a date will still be printed but with `total` is 0, like the expected table I created below

| category | total | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pembuatan | 2 | 8/24/2021 |
| pembuatan | 0 | 8/25/2021 |
| pembuatan | 0 | 8/26/2021 |
| pembuatan | 0 | 8/27/2021 |
| pembuatan | 0 | 8/28/2021 |
| pengiriman | 2 | 8/24/2021 |
| pengiriman | 2 | 8/25/2021 |
| pengiriman | 2 | 8/26/2021 |
| pengiriman | 0 | 8/27/2021 |
| pengiriman | 2 | 8/28/2021 |
| penerimaan | 2 | 8/24/2021 |
| penerimaan | 0 | 8/25/2021 |
| penerimaan | 3 | 8/26/2021 |
| penerimaan | 3 | 8/27/2021 |
| penerimaan | 0 | 8/28/2021 |
| penolakan | 8 | 8/24/2021 |
| penolakan | 4 | 8/25/2021 |
| penolakan | 0 | 8/26/2021 |
| penolakan | 0 | 8/27/2021 |
| penolakan | 0 | 8/28/2021 |
| penghapusan | 5 | 8/24/2021 |
| penghapusan | 0 | 8/25/2021 |
| penghapusan | 0 | 8/26/2021 |
| penghapusan | 0 | 8/27/2021 |
| penghapusan | 0 | 8/28/2021 |
| pengubahan | 2 | 8/24/2021 |
| pengubahan | 0 | 8/25/2021 |
| pengubahan | 0 | 8/26/2021 |
| pengubahan | 0 | 8/27/2021 |
| pengubahan | 0 | 8/28/2021 |

in my expectations table, each category will get the same overall dates as the other categories, but if this seems impossible, how about creating a new "just skipped" date? as is the case in the 'penerimaan' category where there is no date 8/25/2021.
Is this possible?

Sorry for long table, thanks

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Their date/time functions aren't compatible...)

Comment: I removed the conflicting tags, please tag the database you are actually using.

Comment: i'm using MySQL @jarlh , but it's work, using PHPMyAdmin (xampp)

Comment: This is when a calendar table works really well.

Comment: @Larnu hey, your comment little help me thanks, i follow step from this url https://ubiq.co/database-blog/fill-missing-dates-in-mysql/ but my query doesn't work, for that table and calendar table from that url, do you think my query is right?

SELECT l.category, IFNULL(COUNT(l.category), 0) AS total, c.datefield AS tanggal FROM calendar c LEFT JOIN log l ON c.datefield=CAST(l.date AS DATE) GROUP BY l.category, c.datefield ORDER BY l.category ASC LIMIT 100

i try to create/edit this/new question, to make my question more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `CROSS` join of the distinct categories to the distinct dates and then a `LEFT` join to `log` to aggregate on all existing dates:

```
SELECT c.category, 
       COUNT(l.id) total,  
       d.date
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT category FROM log) c
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT DATE(date) date FROM log) d
LEFT JOIN log l ON l.category = c.category AND DATE(l.date) = d.date
GROUP BY c.category, d.date
ORDER BY c.category ASC
LIMIT 100;
```

Note that if there is a date missing from the table for all categories, it will not show in the results with 0 for all categories.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4fc35063b000dd9457ea4bfed68590bf).